# Is there a way to distinguish between digitized and pasted features?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, features, c++

Is there a way to tell if an added feature in QGIS is in fact a newly digitized one or a pasted feature?

I think QGIS is treating both cases in the same way, emitting the same signal:

`QgsVectorLayer::featureAdded(QgsFeatureId fid)`

for a digitized feature as for a pasted one!

Maybe there's a way to tell the difference?

Comment: did u tried comparing feature ids. digitize feature always gives last_fid+1. check what is the feature id from pasted ones. But since both are adding new features qgis or other gis packages may not be able to differentiate. You can paste them in a different layer or add a temporary attribute field and update it only for new/pasted features